# Javascript loader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image carousel on my page with some fairly small images. the issue is not with the images but with the script itself. I want to display a javascript loader image while the entire plugin is loaded and is ready for action.

when i launch the page, the carousel `<li>` first display like a normal list, then get formed into the carousel. i want to avoid that and display a loader image while the entire thing is loaded.

Comment: Do you have *anything* concrete? What carousel? Can you link us to your site, ideally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [this](http://thecodecentral.com/2008/02/21/a-useful-javascript-image-loader) image loader or you can find more image loaders in the internet, you can run image loader indipendently from what page containing. so it is not a part of carousel.